# Can't import csv to postgres on AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, csv, amazon-web-services, pgadmin, rds

I have a Postgres RDS on AWS. Created a table called "store" under schema "public" with the following columns:

[image]

Now I want to import a csv from local to the AWS postgres database.

[image]

I am following the instruction in [this article](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/) to import csv using `PgAdmin`. The AWS database is connected successfully. Then I right clicked on table `store` and chose `Import/Export Data`. The configuration is as follows:

[image]

The columns tab looks fine:

[image]

Once I clicked on "OK", it would say `Import/export job created`.
[image]

However, it never says if the job has finished or not. There is only 100 rows in that csv. I waited a couple minutes and check the data, the table is still empty. Why has the data not been imported to the postgres table using pgadmin import?

Comment: the client is the matter of taste, but if you want reliable "data import", use `psql -c \copy` - Im not saying pgAdmin is bad, but Im saying number of problems with psql today is WAY less then with pgAdmin4... Eg I have outdated version `1.0 rc1` and copy did not even started... btw what version of pgadmin you use?..

Comment: just tried with 1.6 and it crashed with python message - windows is  a mistery to me... btw I tried to do the same with pgadminIII, not IV and it ran remote copy ok

Comment: I second pgAdmin is flaky. Use command line where possible.

Comment: Just tried to use Python with psycopg2 library and it works ok. Will give psql a shot.

Comment: @VaoTsun I've seen they run just command with a back slash, e.g. `\copy`. Where is this type of command run? Does not work in pgAdmin

Comment: no, `\copy` is a `psql` meta command (with same syntax as SQL `COPY`), and psql is a "default" client beloved by most postgressians (including me)

Comment: recent versions of pgadmin4 (version 3.0) will pop-up the postgres error message when you click on the success pop-up. Sounds like pgadmin4 has changed since this question was posted.